# Unable Set Checkbox to Checked in Chrome using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that is broken in the latest version of chrome (32.0.1700.107).  jQuery version is 1.10.1.  This code has been running in other browsers for the last year.  It does work correctly in IE8.  The key section of code is below -

```
var stateWideCb = $('.showStatewide input');
stateWideCb.change(function () {
    var b = $(this).is(':checked');
            $('.showRegion input').attr('checked', b);
    });
```

What happens is that after the first two clicks on the the Master checkbox, the code stops working.

You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/dXczB/1/

Comment: The whole thing can be written `$('.showStatewide input').on("click",function () { $('.showRegion input').prop('checked', this.checked);});`

Comment: `attri` - use with values in html on page load. `prop` - use when an element's 'state' is modified via js for example.

Comment: mplungjan - I'm aware that that is a shorter version.  But temp variables make it easier to troubleshoot problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
.attr('checked', b);
```

to

```
.prop('checked', b);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dXczB/4/)**

As the [jQuery docs on `.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) state:

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the **checked**, selected,
>   or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Comment: From 1.8 onwards, the best is prop. +1